# async onClick with multiple setStates not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

**BACKGROUND**

I have a object that I am referencing to toggle state changes in an onClick event.

```
const map = {
      active: {
        name: "sliceA",
        toggle: (map) => map.inactive
      },
      inactive: {
        name: "sliceB",
        toggle: (map) => map.active
      }
    }
```

useState of component either holds `map.acive` or `map.inactive` slice of object via a transition function.

```
const [slice, setSlice] = useState(map.active);

const transition = (getMethod) => {
    const getNewSlice = getMethod(slice);
    const result = getNewSlice(map);
    setSlice(result);
  };
```

This works as I expect until you attempt multiple state changes in a single onClick event.

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      transition(slice => slice.toggle);
      await stall();
      transition(slice => slice.toggle);
    } catch (err) {}
  };
```

**ISSUE**

See link - [codesandbox1](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-hill-j048do)

If you click button X1 the 2nd transition() in handleClick() will not trigger state change.

If you click button X2 the 2nd transition() in handleClick() will trigger state change.

**REQUEST**

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix? I made another more manual way of setting state and it operates as expected - [codesandbox2](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-gates-owv8l8)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I'm guessing that means one or two "times"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is both `transition` calls in one `handleClick` call refer to the state of `slice` from the render call `transition` was defined in. In other words, `setState` doesn't update the `slice` the `transtion` has a closure over.

To make it always act on the *current* state, use a callback setter. `currentSlice` will be updated between render calls as well:

```
const transition = (getMethod) => {
  setSlice((currentSlice) => {
    const getNewSlice = getMethod(currentSlice);
    return getNewSlice(map);
  });
};
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wescoff-ft176y)

Comment: ugh - Thank you! I did find `setState(currentState => {...})` threads in relation to async events when searching. My attempts at fixing `transition` didnt work ha..